# Progress Bar is not working

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me how the progress bar work? In my HTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
      <script type="javascript/text">
         var progress = setInterval(function() {
             var $bar = $('.bar');

             if ($bar.width()==400) {
                clearInterval(progress);
                $('.progress').removeClass('active');
             } else {
                $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
             }
             $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
         }, 800);
      </script>
    </head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

In my CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
   margin-top: 30px;
   width: 400px;
}
```

what's wrong with it? I can't get anything after run it.
I was run it at sever too.
I get it from here: http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/
please help.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? I don't see a problem...

Comment: when i run it nothing is coming.

Comment: can you able to run this code??

Comment: Works fine here. Are you using IE6 or something?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, the progress bar steps towards 100% in 10% increments. I'm using the latest version of Firefox, are you using something older?

Comment: I am getting only the blank bar. why? r u run in server or only double click on the html file? I run it firefox too, same here. can u send me your complete file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include `bootstrap.js` in your code - in fiddler this is included dynamically by checkbox on leftside. Install bootsrap properly in your standalone code.

Comment: Yes, u r write. I am not able to run any code from fiddler. How can i install bootstrap.js. Please tell me the process.

Comment: Here you have example (a Bootstrapped template): http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#html-template. Note that you have to place CSS and JS files in your project.

Comment: The progress Bar works but something is wrong.A big Progress Bar is coming which fills till 100% but reach 100% at half of the bar. how to correct it?? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<script type='text/javascript'>` instead of `<script type='javascript/text'>` in your code...

Or even just `<script>` without the type attribute, pretty much all browsers will interpret it as javascript these days.

EDIT - @killer_PL also has a point - that file will need to be included as well. Didn't think of that...

Comment: Not coming. I import bootstrap.js in css & it is accessible when i click on the link in css.

Comment: @SomnathKayal Ok, but have you replaced `javascript/text` with `text/javascript`?

Comment: yes. i have tried both text/javascript & only <script>. I think bootstrap.js occurs problem. how to fix this? please suggest.